# Rails 5/Bootstrap 4: My Navbar Displays a Mobile Dropdown Menu on Desktop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, navbar

This is my first time using Bootstrap 4. With Bootstrap 3 I rarely used the nav class.

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 template. I have copied the entire stylesheet as is. I'm able to get it working except for the navbar. When I open the template directly it works as expected. However, my version shows the css buttons in the drop-down menu instead of horizontally on the desktop.

Here is what the menu should look like:

[image]

Here is what my menu looks like:

[image]

I've tried on the latest versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. All of them look exactly the same.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**application.scss**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

**header (before updates)**

```
<header>
  <div class="tm-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="tm-header-inner">
                <%= link_to "Classic", locale_root_path, class: "navbar-brand tm-site-name" %>

          <!-- navbar -->
          <nav class="navbar tm-main-nav">

              <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tmNavbar">&#9776;</button>

              <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="tmNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home", locale_root_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Blog", blog_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
                </ul>                        
              </div>

          </nav>  

        </div>     

    </div>                                  
  </div> 
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1390px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 40px;
}

.nav-item.active .nav-link,
.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: #cc9900;

}

.tm-header-inner {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100px;
}

.tm-site-name {
    color: #cc9900;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.tm-main-nav { font-size: 1.2rem; }
```

As I continued to look I saw that the template is using an alpha version of Bootstrap 4. I changed all the hidden-xx-up classes to the corresponding d-xx-none d-yy-block where yy is the next higher responsive class. For example, in the header, I changed `hidden-md-up` to `d-md-none d-lg-block`.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none d-lg-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tmNavbar">&#9776;</button>
```

I've done a lot of web searching today, including on the Bootstrap website, but cannot find any information about what to replace `navbar-toggleable-xx` with. None of the navbar examples I have found use `navbar-toggleable-xx` so I assume they are using the current stable version.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="tmNavbar">
```

How do I modify this to get my navbar working? I will keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `navbar-toggleable-*` class group in Bootstrap 4 (anymore).

Replace `navbar-toggleable-sm` with `navbar-expand-sm`.

That's the class for **expanding** the navbar from the desired breakpoint onwards. So, the `sm` in `navbar-expand-sm` means: the navbar will be expanded from the small (`sm`) screen size and up.

### Important:

You cannot really use your current code at all with Bootstrap 4.

So, even if you replace `navbar-toggleable-sm` with `navbar-expand-sm` in your code, it still isn't gonna work because your code is *not* Bootstrap 4 code.

Here's what a working Bootstrap 4 navbar looks like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Next step: Reading the docs for Bootstrap 4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Before you posted your update to your comments I started looking again at the documentation and realized that I had to rewrite it somewhat. The first time I read this I thought that I needed to replace the clause where it was in my code but I found that I needed to move the navbar-expand-sm class. I have a couple of minor changes to make but I'm seeing my menu horizontally as desired.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer after taking a closer look and realizing that you'll have to do more than just replacing one class.

Comment: I learned my lesson. The template documentation did not say which version of Bootstrap 4 was being used. When I checked the download and saw the bootstrap files in the template were created in December 2015 I knew I was probably dealing with different versions of Bootstrap 4. I just need to move some of my CSS around for the navbar and I will have that change done. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox-based by default and those parts that aren't flexbox-based by default can be easily switched to flexbox with native Bootstrap 4 classes. It is therefore recommended to stay away from unnecessary css hacks as they tend to mess things up and require even more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks. Basically, anything flexbox-related in your custom css can be deleted.

Comment: There is a little bit of flexbox code I believe. Thankfully the CSS is not that long and easy to work with. I like using the original version of software whenever possible :)

Upvote done. I meant to do that before.